# Windows show local path as list in the Environmental Variables pane

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

I like to modify my Windows environmental variables by opening the `Advanced System Settings -> Environmental Variables`. I particularly like that when I try to modify the system path (by clicking on `System Variables -> Path`), that I get a nice, easy to read list of the folders on the path:

[image]

However, when I click on the `User Variables -> Path`, I still get the old dialog, which is not very user friendly:

[image]

Is it possible to have Windows always display the list, as is the case for the System variables?

For what its worth, I think I remember seeing the desired behavior on a friend's computer, so I believe it should be possible.

EDIT:

It seems that having a variable as part of the path is the problem. Is there a way to get path list even when the path contains variables?

Context: 
When I want to add a program to my path, I will create a new variable that redirects to its path. The reason to do that is simple... Programs typically have compound paths, and so making a consolidated variable seems like a wise decision. For instance, on my machine, I have multiple python instances (sometimes I need an Anaconda installation of Python 3.6, and sometimes I want a version of the bare-bones Python 3.5). To accomodate this, I create environmental variables for the paths to each installation.

[image]

Now if I want to switch which version is on my path, I can simply update my path variable from

```
path=...;%PATH_PYTHON35%
```

to

```
path=...;%PATH_PYTHON36A%
```

See how easy that was?

The problem is that the GUI doesn't seem to like this for the local variables. I can confirm that this is the case because when I remove the variables from the local path, I get the nice list like the System Variables case. However, what is perplexing to me is that the System Variables path DOES include some variables as well:

[image]

So I take this to mean that there must be a way of getting the local variables list to pop up, just like the System Variables case...

Comment: It should display the new dialog automatically for any variable whenever the value looks like a list of file-system paths delimited by semicolons. Try adding a directory at a time to see which path makes it revert to the single-line text editor.

Comment: Variables that get used in `PATH` (e.g. `PATH_PYTHON36` ) can't themselves have dependencies. The environment is loaded in 4 passes: (1) system `REG_SZ` variables with no dependencies, (2) system `REG_EXPAND_SZ` variables (e.g. the system `PATH`) that depend on previously-loaded system `REG_SZ` variables, (3) user `REG_SZ` variables with no dependencies, (4) user `REG_EXPAND_SZ` variables (e.g. the user `PATH`)  that can depend on all system variables and `REG_SZ` user variables.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you other than they DO work on my system. I have been using this pattern for years. One of the reasons I started doing it was that it made figuring out what was on the path much easier when we didn't have the nice list GUI

Comment: I was just clarifying the rules for creating environment variables that depend on other variables. It's fine as long as the `PATH_PYTHON*` variables don't depend on other variables.

Comment: As to the dialog, as I said, this is based on a heuristic that guesses whether the string is a semicolon-delimited list of filesystem paths. I know it does work with individual paths in variables. You'll have to systematically experiment, trying permutations until you discover what's causing the problem. Start with appending only one `PATH_PYTHON` variable that has only one directory.

Answer (score 3):

Guess I'm late to the party, but this works for me:
PATH=C:\DATA\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin
whereas this does not work:
PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\DATA\bin

Answer (score 1):

A speculation based on my own observations.

It seems list view is only presented when at least one of the first **two** entries begins either with a drive letter notation (like `C:\`) or a specific variable. I'm not sure which variables are considered "valid", but here are a few environmental variables that show up as list:

- `%USERPROFILE%+%LOCALAPPDATA%;aaa;bbb;`
- `aaa;Q:\%LOCALAPPDATA%;bbb;`

These however show up as a string:

- `%LOCALAPPDATA%+%USERPROFILE%;aaa;bbb;`
- `aaa;bbb;%USERPROFILE%;`

Not sure what makes `%USERPROFILE%` different, but i tried a few other variables instead of `%LOCALAPPDATA%` (`%OS%`, `%HOMEDRIVE%`) - result was the same.